# How can I use Gulp to add a line of text to a file

Tags: file, gulp, edit, inject

I've been trying to figure out how to add a line of text to any type of file using Gulp.

For instance add:

```
@import 'plugins'
```

to my main.sass file.

Or add a CDN to an index.html file.

I did try:

```
gulp.task('inject-plugins', function(){
   gulp.src('src/css/main.sass')
    .pipe(inject.after('// Add Imports', '\n@import \'plugins\'\n'));
});
```

with no joy. Any idea how I could achieve this please?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.

If you just want to add text to the beginning or end of a file [`gulp-header`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header) and [`gulp-footer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-footer) are your friends:

```
var header = require('gulp-header');
var footer = require('gulp-footer');

gulp.task('add-text-to-beginning', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/css/main.sass')
    .pipe(header('@import \'plugins\'\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('add-text-to-end', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/css/main.sass')
    .pipe(footer('@import \'plugins\''))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If you have some kind of "anchor" text in your file you can use [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace):

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('replace-text', function() {
  var anchor = '// Add Imports';
  return gulp.src('src/css/main.sass')
    .pipe(replace(anchor, anchor + '\n@import \'plugins\'\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Finally there's the swiss army knife of vinyl file manipulation: [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream). This gives you direct access to file contents and allows you to do any kind of string manipulation that you can think of in JavaScript:

```
var map = require('map-stream');

gulp.task('change-text', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/css/main.sass')
    .pipe(map(function(file, cb) {
      var fileContents = file.contents.toString();
      // --- do any string manipulation here ---
      fileContents = fileContents.replace(/foo/, 'bar');
      fileContents = 'First line\n' + fileContents;
      // ---------------------------------------
      file.contents = new Buffer(fileContents);
      cb(null, file);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add those libraries!
If you are using npm: add them to "devDependencies": {..} in package.json file, and run "npm install"

Comment: in case, if i want to add pone line in same file, how can i give dest location?

Comment: seems like `map-stream` is deprecated