# Gulp task for add one new line to particular file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-task

How to add one line to required file using gulp task?

This is my file:

```
export { NumericTextBoxComponent} from './numerictextbox/numerictextbox.component';
export { NumericTextBoxModule } from './numerictextbox/numerictextbox.module';
export { NumericTextBoxAllModule } from './numerictextbox/numerictextbox-all.module';
export * from '@syncfusion/ej2-inputs';
```

Here I want to add one new line which is:

```
export { EJsvalidator} from './form-validator/form-validator';
```

How can i do?

I tried like this :

```
var footer = require('gulp-footer');
gulp.task('add', function() {
    return gulp.src('./third-party/angular/src/index.ts')
           .pipe(footer("export { EJsvalidator} from './form-validator/form-validator';"))
           .pipe(gulp.dest('./third-party/angular/src/index.ts'));
});
```

> If i execute this task, it shows following error:

```js
PS D:\ej2-input-component> gulp add
[14:29:09] Using gulpfile D:\ej2-input-component\gulpfile.js
[14:29:09] Starting 'add'...
[14:29:09] 'add' errored after 15 ms
[14:29:09] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\ej2-input-component\third-party\angular\src\index.ts'
PS D:\ej2-input-component>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Gulp to add a line of text to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374936/how-can-i-use-gulp-to-add-a-line-of-text-to-a-file)

Comment: Hi @JeremyThille, i am new to this .can you please show another one example...

Comment: Well, I can [google around](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+add+a+line+of+text+to+a+file+using+gulp&oq=how+to+add+a+line+of+text+to+a+file+using+gulp&aqs=chrome..69i57.10038j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and it will give me plenty of relevant results about how to do this :)

Comment: still, i did not get a point.

Comment: i tried like this......                                                                                            
 var footer = require('gulp-footer');
gulp.task('add', function() {
    return gulp.src('./third-party/angular/src/index.ts')
      .pipe(footer("export { EJsvalidator} from './form-validator/form-validator';"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./third-party/angular/src/index.ts'));
  });

Comment: And what did it do? Nothing? Did you execute that task?

Comment: yes i executed that task it shows following error:

Comment: PS D:\ej2-input-component> gulp add
[14:29:09] Using gulpfile D:\ej2-input-component\gulpfile.js
[14:29:09] Starting 'add'...
[14:29:09] 'add' errored after 15 ms
[14:29:09] Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'D:\ej2-input-component\third-party\angular\src\index.ts'
PS D:\ej2-input-component>

Comment: The documentations says `gulp.dest('./dist/')`, so maybe try `gulp.dest('./third-party/angular/src/')` ?

Comment: love you friend, it works thank you

Comment: post this as your answer i will accept but one more small pblm , i want to add it into next line but it is adding continues of last line

Comment: Just add a newline \n to the beginning of your footer, like "\n export...…….."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentations says `gulp.dest('./dist/')`, so maybe try `gulp.dest('./third-party/angular/src/')`.

Also, about your comment :

> one more small pblm , i want to add it into next line but it is adding
>   continues of last line

Yes, that's the point of `gulp-footer`, it is *made* to add lines in the footer, which means at the end of the file :) There are more flexible modules, like [gulp-insert-lines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-insert-lines).

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help :)