# Gulp function to create a file with contents

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm pretty new to gulp and trying to figure out if it's possible to write a gulp function that creates a file for me, with some content, and places the files in a location. But I'm trying to create files with the same name of other files.

Here's my current setup:

```
dist
src
---modules
------item1.njk
------item2.njk
---new files
```

For each file in the modules folder I want to create an .njk file with the same name but different file contents. File contents are currently HTML but I want to write new code in the newly created files.

**Intended output:**

src/modules/item1.njk has contents:

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

src/modules/item2.njk has contents:

```
<p>Hello again, World!</p>
```

I want these file names to be used when creating these files with new contents:

src/new files/item1.njk has contents:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles.css">
{% block content %}
{% include "modules/item1.njk" %}
{% endblock %}
```

src/new files/item2.njk has contents:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles.css">
{% block content %}
{% include "modules/item2.njk" %}
{% endblock %}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the map-stream suggestion from this answer that allowed me to edit the file contents before pushing it to a new folder location:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376568/5900050

My final script didn't need the original file contents, I wanted to replace it all which got me here:

```
.pipe(map(function(file, cb) {
  var fileName = file.basename.toString();
  // --- do any string manipulation here ---
  fileContents = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles.css">\n{% block content %}\n{% include "modules/body/'+fileName+'" %}\n{% endblock %}';
  // ---------------------------------------
  file.contents = new Buffer.from(fileContents);
  cb(null, file);
}))
```